# How to remove the title name and app icon from the appication UI?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

[image: remove app icon and tile]

I want to use my own title.I think app icon and application name automatically comes while installing the app.I have made my own customized image and i want to use it as title.I have used the below code but it is  not working for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);


}
```

}

titlebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/titlebar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in your activity to remove the default title

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
}
```

and in your xml create your own custom title using linearlayout having textview and ImageView

Comment: So i tried, now appicon and appname gone.I want to use titlebar.xml as my titile so that my customized titlebar image can be used.So can i use an xml as my titlebar?? (Or) Is it necessary to add textview and imageview-where i need to set that titlebar image.??

Comment: yes you can do that follow this http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from manifest file also,

Change the **appname** in **res/values/string.xml** file. So, the **title** of your app will change.

Now put the icon in drawable folder which you want to use for your app and

Go to **AndroidManifest.xml** -> select **Application** -> you can change icon from here : select your **icon** from drawable for **icon** field

**[image: icon]**

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to accomplish

You can change it from manifest file also,

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.MAPit.Volley.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mapit"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

just put the app_name in `strings.xml` and icon in `res/drawable` folder.

If you want to change it in code call

```
setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

And set the values to whatever you please.

In XML:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
       android:label="My new title" />
```

To enable the back button in your app use

```
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The code should all be placed in your onCreate so that the label/icon changing is transparent to the user, but in reality it can be called anywhere during the activity's lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

you can hide your title bar with the single line

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

and if you want to customize the the bar or heading with some buttons or functional widgets then customize action bar  and use Support action bar for lower api level.

Answer (score 0):

use this string before setContentView:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jyomin answer or i tried from different answers found on stackoverflow

titlebar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/titlebar"
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

     <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

     setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);

     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
    // getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.);

}
```

}

And use this line in manifest which activity tag you are going to use

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
```

like this

```
<activity android:name="com.bar.start.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme">
```